# 404 not found error, can't redirect to another page/view

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am having a problem with the routing.
Firstly, I am on the page (rate product)/{$id}

[image]

Next, when clicking the button, I want to go to another view (addReview/{$productID}/{$clientID}) But it gives me an error.

-web.php file

```
Route::get('rateProduct/{id}', 'CatalogController@getProduct')
    ->name('rateProduct');

Route::post('./addReview/{$productID}/{$clientID}','ReviewController@addReview')
    ->name('rateProduct.addReview');
```

add_review.blade.php

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <form method="post" action="{{url('rateProduct.addReview', [$product->id, 10]) }} value="{{ csrf_token() }}"">
    {{--{{ csrf_field() }}--}}
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Share your thoughts!</label>
        <textarea class="form-control rounded" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
                    placeholder="Tell us about your experiecnce in a couple of sentences" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

ReviewController.php

```
class ReviewController extends Controller
{
    public function addReview($productID, $clientID)
    {
        if(isset( $_POST['submit'])) {
            $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        }
    
        $date = date_create();
        $reviewID = DB::table('review')->max('id') + 1;
        $data = array(
            'id'=>$reviewID,
            "comment"=>$comment,
            "review_date"=>date_timestamp_get($date),
            "rating"=>1,
            "client_id"=>$clientID
        );
        DB::table('review')->insert($data);
        $data2 = array('product_id'=>$productID,"review_id"=>$reviewID);
        DB::table('product_review')->insert($data2);

        return view('pages/product-page');
    }
}
```

Review model

```
class Review extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'Review';

    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
}
```

Comment: Pardon me if I am wrong. Could you please confirm this view is present `return view('pages/product-page');`. Because this function `addReview` returning to that page and I am not sure if that page is present.

Comment: yes it is, I tried with several different ones, but nothing happens

Comment: Dont use `$` on route parameter `Route::post('./addReview/{productID}/{clientID}','ReviewController@addReview')->name('rateProduct.addReview');`

Comment: uh right! did that, nothing changes :( 
This is the url i am getting: http://localhost:8000/addReview/2/10%20value=

Answer (score 0):

You have error in routing .Remove dot from the beginning(`./addReview/{$productID}/{$clientID}`) of string in post method.

```
Route::post('addReview/{$productID}/{$clientID}','ReviewController@addReview')->name('rateProduct.addReview');
```

Also you are using `url method` for `named routing` in `form action` it should be

```
  <form method="post" action="{{route('rateProduct.addReview', [$product->id, 10]) }}" >
 @csrf
```

Comment: you have error in action="{{url('rateProduct.addReview', [$product->id, 10]) }} it should be {{route('rateProduct.addReview',[$product->id, 10])

Comment: just verify in inspecting element what action url is showing

Comment: @MonikaStepien.its clear you have error in form action so copy paste from my answer and try once

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have a random `.` at the start of your route and `$` symbols in your parameters, they needs to go.

```php
Route::post('/addReview/{productID}/{clientID}','ReviewController@addReview')
    ->name('rateProduct.addReview');
```

Next you need to fix the invalid markup of your `add_review` blade file, you have mismatched opening/closing elements. You are also using a `named route` but using the `url` helper which works with `paths` rather than route names. You also want to add back in the `@csrf` token back in otherwise you'll get a `419` error.

```html
<div class="mb-3">
    <form method="post"
        action="{{ route('rateProduct.addReview', [$product->id, 10]) }}">
        @csrf
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">
            Share your thoughts!
        </label>
        <textarea class="form-control rounded"
            id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="Tell us about your experiecnce in a couple of sentences"
            name="comment">
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can see a [working example here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/black-pond-xzeq-mzs5d).